# Андроид.  is not translated in //языки//

Tags: android, eclipse, цифровая-подпись

Приложение написанно, но когда я хочу собрать его и подписать, для каждой строки в strings выбивает "is not translated in...". Что с этим делать? Вручную создавать список этих переводов и копировать английскую версию? И никак не ускорить это дело? Короче, что с этим делать?

Comment: Положить strings.xml в папку values, а не values-ru

Comment: Аналогичная ошибка и strings.xml лежит именно в папке values

Answer (score 1):

я решил проблему вот так, добавив флаг **translatable="false"**

```
<string name="my_res_string" translatable="false">some text</string>
```